# Discord.js command timeout

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots, replit

I have a command where it asks a question and gives different responses based on the answer, and that part works, but the command doest end, meaning that if you reply to a new instance of the command, the first instance and the new instance will reply. I tried different timeout functions but nothing worked.
here's the code:

```
module.exports = {
name: 'test',
description: "test comand",
execute(message, args, Discord) {
    message.channel.send("Do you want to test this command?\n `Yes`, `No` or `Mayhaps`")
    console.log(message.author.id)
    const collector = new Discord.MessageCollector(message.channel, m => m.author.id === member, { time: 10000 });
    collector.on('collect', message => {
        if (message.content.toUpperCase() == "YES") {
            message.channel.send("Let's Go! It worked!");
    } else if (message.content.toUpperCase() == "NO") {
            message.channel.send( "Task failed successfully.");
     } else if (message.content.toUpperCase() == "MAYHAPS") {
            message.channel.send("ERROR: IT WORKED ANYWAY");
        }
})
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you are not stopping the collector, try:

```
collector.stop();
```

after all the conditions.

Also, you need to check that the message sent is from a user and not from the bot, since you are not awaiting the first message to send before starting the collector.

```
message.channel.send("Do you want to test this command?\n `Yes`, `No` or `Mayhaps`")
```

The colletor is collecting that message, which is from the bot, so you are stopping the collector with the bot message, not giving a chance to reply.

Final result:

```
collector.on("collect", async (message) => {
    if (message.content.toUpperCase() == "YES") {
        await message.channel.send("Let's Go! It worked!");
    } else if (message.content.toUpperCase() == "NO") {
        await message.channel.send("Task failed successfully.");
    } else if (message.content.toUpperCase() == "MAYHAPS") {
        await message.channel.send("ERROR: IT WORKED ANYWAY");
    }
    if (!message.author.bot) collector.stop();
});
```

In case you don't want to check if the message is from a bot, you can await the first message like this:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'test',
    description: "test comand",
    async execute(message, args, Discord) {
        await message.channel.send("Do you want to test this command?\n `Yes`, `No` or `Mayhaps`")
        console.log(message.author.id)
        const collector = new Discord.MessageCollector(message.channel, m => m.author.id === member, { time: 10000 });
        collector.on('collect', message => {
            if (message.content.toUpperCase() == "YES") {
                message.channel.send("Let's Go! It worked!");
            } else if (message.content.toUpperCase() == "NO") {
                message.channel.send( "Task failed successfully.");
            } else if (message.content.toUpperCase() == "MAYHAPS") {
                message.channel.send("ERROR: IT WORKED ANYWAY");
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: When I add that, the part of the command in the collector, ie, the response, doesn't work.

Comment: You may need to make it async and await the send commands

Comment: How do I do that? Sorry but I'm new to coding and don't know much. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: I've just edited the answer, try that code.

Comment: It still doesn't seem to work. When I reply with yes, nothing happens

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: No error, the bot just doesn't reply

Comment: Sory for taking so long, there is the answer.

Comment: Now we're back to the original problem, where the command doesn't stop collecting responses. I cant send images, so heres an Imgur link:

Comment: Sorry had some technical problems. Here's the image link: https://imgur.com/a/5WSwU4q             And about checking if message is from bot, I already have that set up in my command handler, so that's ok.